# SQL compilation

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, compilation

Java is compiled into Binary code and executed by JVM.
C++ is compiled into platform dependent code.

When I read definition of Stored Procedure in SQL Server, it says
A stored procedure is a group of Transact-SQL statements **compiled** into a single execution plan.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx

So what is SQL compiled into (something SQL Server can execute..?) ?  Could I say stored procedure is pre-compiled and ready to execute so it is faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe "compilation" with stored procedures simply means "creation and storage of a query execution plan."

According to the blog post [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/08/sql-server-stored-procedure-are-compiled-on-first-run-sp-taking-longer-to-run-first-time/), stored procs are checked for syntax when `create`d or `alter`ed, but only compiled when they are first run. That link also gives scripts you can run to tell you if a given procedure has been compiled or not.

For more reading, see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc966425.aspx) Microsoft article on compilation in Sql Server 2005.